# IMPORTING DATA - Is there a sequence when it comes to importing?

Tags: data-loader, metadata, import

It there an actual way to import records?  I know the sequence is this for standard objects 
1.  Accounts 
2.  Campaigns 
3.  Contacts 
4.  Opportunities 
5.  Cases 
6.  Solutions 
7.  Pricebooks 
8.  Products 
9.  Leads 
10.Contracts 
 
but I have a lot of custom object which i'm not worried about.  My question to you is most of my records have ID that is reference to another record.  Will I be able to import those RECORD ID's?

Right now I'm having a problem importing USERS because it uses a different Profile ID and now my USER ID's are different which I know it will be a conflict on any data I import.  Any suggestions?
My final queation, how do I import properly even with the ID's imported?
 Im using DATALOADER by the way.

Comment: It is a very painful process. If you have master detail relationship, first load master and get the ids and assign for detail records and then load. For lookup relationships you can load the records, get the ids and then do upsert. You will have to use vlookup alot. I wish there was an easy process :)

Comment: @javanoob I totally get you.  I thought its a simple upload but it makes sense.  so I have to start with the Profiles > Roles > Users > Account >.... etc.  To make it worst...  This is the Demo upload but I need to upload all of them hahaha

Comment: Are you doing upload from one salesorce org to another salesforce org?

Comment: @javanoob Yes.  from a managed database to a new one.

Comment: Then you are in luck :) I did something like this few weeks ago. I was lazy to do upload, vlookup and all that manual steps so I followed the approach mentioned in this article http://www.codeulike.com/2014/02/copying-data-to-salesforce-sandboxes.html and it worked like charm. Now data flows between one SF to another SF in just minutes and no more manual steps and another cool thing is it is a one time setup and you can load whenever you want with just one single button click.